# Check properties of recursive object in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an object like in below stackblitz and I want to check if key is Date or not. And then I'm adding 3 days to that date. I'm doing for this for not recursive object perfectly. But, when object is recursive, I couldn't do this. How can I achieve this? **Performance is important for me because in my real life scenario my objects are very big and complex.**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykh1r5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
  myObject = {
    aProperty: {
      aSetting1: 1,
      aSetting2: new Date(),
      aSetting3: 3,
      aSetting4: 4,
      aSetting5: 5
    },
    bProperty: {
      bSetting1: {
        bPropertySubSetting: new Date()
      },
      bSetting2: "bString"
    },
    cProperty: {
      cSetting: new Date()
    },
    dProperty: new Date()
  }


  convertButtonClick() {
    this.convert(this.myObject);
    console.log(this.myObject);
  }

  convert(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (obj[property] instanceof Date) {
          obj[property].setDate(obj[property].getDate() + 3);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have to traverse whole object, For that you need to use recursion. Or use BFS, DFS traversal

Comment: I tried recursion but, I didn't achieve @Amit

Comment: If your lucky based on some domain knowledge you could speed up the process.  e.g as from depth/level 3 there wouldn't be any more dates down. or for e.g there are never more than x dates in 1 level.

Comment: Thanks @jcuypers and Amit. ConnorsFan 's answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `convert` recursively when you find that one of the properties is an object:

```
convert(obj) {
  for (let property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (obj[property] instanceof Date) {
        obj[property].setDate(obj[property].getDate() + 3);
      } else if (obj[property] instanceof Object) {
        this.convert(obj[property]);  // Recursive call
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mlihs?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ConnorsFan. This is what I was looking for.